# Load Full Calendar events using Codeigniter3

Tags: php, json, fullcalendar, codeigniter-3, fullcalendar-3

How to show Calendar Events stored in Database using Codeigniter3???

I got the data in alert message by using following code...

```
$.post('<?php echo site_url('Calendar/getEvents');?>',
   function(data){
        alert(data);
      });
```

But on Calendar my Events data is not displaying,
 The following is my code...

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function(){
$.post('<?php echo site_url('Calendar/getEvents');?>',
function(data){
   alert(data);
});
var calendar = $("#calendar").fullCalendar({
header:{
    left   : 'prev,next today',
    center : 'title',
    right  : 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay,listWeek'
    },
events      : '<?php echo site_url('Calendar/getEvents');?>',
    </script>
```

Please help me and give solution as early as possible....

Comment: You'll need to show us the JSON which the URL returns. Presumably it is not returning the event data in a format recognised by fullCalendar. See https://fullcalendar.io/docs/v3/event-object and https://fullcalendar.io/docs/v3/events-array for info.

Comment: P.s. we have discussed a very similar topic before. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57273520/events-adding-and-loading-problem-in-jquery-full-calendar-using-sql-server-and-p . I would have hoped by now you would know how to figure this problem out based on that

Comment: Ya, that time I got result... But that time I used core PHP, but my project is Codeigniter

Comment: I used same as     "events      : '<?php echo site_url('Calendar/getEvents');?>',"                But this is not working in Codeigniter...

Comment: You said you got the data in the alert. That was from the same URL. So please show me that data

Comment: P.s. one thing I noticed just now is your first request is $.post() ...so it will use HTTP POST method. Whereas by default fullCalendar will use a GET request. If you check your browser's Network tools you could see this, and you could also see if the request fails for that reason (or any other).

Comment: That alert data is not copying....How can I attach my output window

Comment: Yes that's true, you can't copy from an alert box. But you can just write the same data into the console e.g. `console.log(data);` instead of alert, and then you can copy it from there. Or you could get it from the Response tab of the AJAX request if you look at it in your Network tools in the browser. (If you are writing JavaScript code you really need to ensure you are familiar with these tools so you can use them for debugging tasks like this. `alert()` is not a debugging tool).

Comment: [{"id":"4","title":"Meeting2","start":"2019-07-31 00:00:00.000","end":"2019-07-31 00:00:00.000"},{"id":"10003","title":"Meeting2","start":"2019-02-08 00:00:00.000","end":"2019-03-08 00:00:00.000"}]

Comment: My Controller File Code:                                                                              public function getEvents()
 {
 
  $query = $this->db->get('events');

  $timezone = new DateTimeZone("UTC");

  foreach($query->result_array() as $row)
  {
   $data[] = array(
    'id'    => $row['id'],
    'title' => $row['title'],
    'start' => $row['start_event'],//->format("Y-m-d H:i:s"),
    'end'   => $row['end_event']//->format("Y-m-d H:i:s")
   );
  }


  echo json_encode($data);
  
 }

Comment: If we do a simple test and hard-code those events we can see that the format in which the dates are produced is not an issue: http://jsfiddle.net/9a86h74m/

Comment: P.S. in future please [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/57831418/edit) and don't add code or data in comments. The "edit" button is just below the blue "php" and "json" tags. Thanks.

Comment: Anyway I suspect this all comes down to the GET / POST issue I mentioned yesterday (see my earlier comments). Did you try to verify that as I suggested?

Comment: If that's the issue then you can either a) tell CodeIgniter to allow a GET request to your controller method (I don't know CodeIgniter, so you'd have to go and find out how to do that), **or** b) tell fullCalendar to make a POST request to the URL (like this: `events: { "url": '<?php echo site_url('Calendar/getEvents');?>', "type": "POST" },` Documentation for that: https://fullcalendar.io/docs/v3/events-json-feed